# Link http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.2.1/sencha-touch-all.js not Working

Tags: sencha-touch-2.2

Hi am working on Secncha Application and i use Sencha Architect. When you create a new project in Architect, by default it reference to the links given below for sencha js file and css file. But these links are not working anymore is the path changed ? my application is giving me the error 
**GET http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.2.1/resources/css/sencha-touch.css 404 (Not Found)
GET http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.2.1/sencha-touch-all.js 404 (Not Found)**

Comment: The link is broken - so what?

Comment: Personally I like google: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?247207-Using-Sencha-CDN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Project Inspector -> Resources -> Library change setting "Library Base Path" to a local folder containing Sencha Touch Library. If you are using default Architect Settings, just enter touch/ (don't forget slash)

Comment: Hi motilio, I have changed the reference location of the file as mentioned and now its working fine....

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution is to copy those files from your sencha touch sdk folder, in to your app folder (that XAMPP is looking at) and change the app.html accordingly.

for example:

```
<script src="sencha-touch-all.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/sencha-touch.css">
```

Comment: Hi nikil511, I have changed the reference location of the file as mentioned and now its working fine.. Thanks